# double scroll on win 7 and ie 9 Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-9, google-maps-api-2

I have problem with scrolling that occure only on ie 9 and win 7.

Desired action is:
- when cursor is above the map: scrolling makes zoom in and zoom out
- when cursor is above the sidebar: scrolling makes page up and page down.

Unfortunately on abovementioned combination scrolling make both. zooming and moving up and down.

Why it is happening?

Comment: I've had this happen to me on FireFox as well.

Comment: Solved! Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11187097/1230507